# Compiler warning "may not respond to"

Tags: objective-c

I'm a rank newbie, so please excuse me.

I'm working with a barcode reader sample program from zbar. I wanted to add a sqlite3 daabase for looking up barcodes scanned. The but when I try to instance the sql control from the ViewController I get the following error.

```
MySQL *MS =[[MySQL alloc ] init];

[ MS viewDidLoad];
  ^^   MySQL may not respond to viewDidLoad
```

Any ideas? Thanks

PS The program crashes once it hits the offending line.

Comment: If we helped please don't forget to mark an answer as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

"May not respond to" means that your object may not implement the method you want to call. Your program crashes because it's essentially calling a method that does not exist.

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do, but I don't think an object "MySQL" would have a viewDidLoad method.

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible causes of “may not respond to”. Either:

1. You forgot to inclue a header file import for the appropriate class.
2. The method doesn't exist on the class you're calling it on.

Number 2 looks far more likely in your case.

Comment: I coded the viewDidLoad method. But I could name it anything. It's the method that I use to open the database. I created a MySQL.h file. I tried to post it but it's too big.

Comment: There may very well be some kind of format error in the .h file.